# Postgres CIC triggers create index of other existing index

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a very large table with ~500 mil records. This table already has index on 3 fields

```
CREATE TABLE temp (id bigserial primary key, min_timestamp timestamp with time zone, max_timestamp timestamp with time zone, orgname varchar); 

min_timestamp index_1
max_timestamp index_2
orgname       index_3
```

I am trying to create concurrent multi column index_4 on `(orgname, min_timestamp, max_timestamp)`.

When the `CREATE CIC index_4` executes it also executes automatically create index of index_2 which already exists.

question:

1. Why is index_2 getting executed which is already existing?
2. index_2 is blocked by index_4 and results in deadlock after several hours. How to over come this?

Environment: AWS RDS Postgres ver: 9.6

Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: You are giving us your conclusions, but they just don't make sense.  What are you observing that makes you think this is happening?

Comment: My observation:

Comment: When I try to create CIC on multiple columns of a table i see one more create CIC triggered on a column for which index already exists. Is this behaviour expected ?

15196 | CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY temp_org_timestamp_idx on temp(orgname, min_timestamp, max_timestamp); ->> I executed this
31555 | create INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS temp_max_timestamp_idx ON temp (max_timestamp);          ->> I did not execute this.

Comment: Someone (or something) executed it.  If people are running things without your knowledge and permission, maybe you should change your passwords.

Comment: You should explain what CIC is.